# iOS Provisioning Profiles (Distribution)

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I want to create new `IOS Provisioning profile` for `existing bundle id` but it gives me an error. Please help

I create IOS for same name 
[image]

but admin did something and make **invalid** it. Now he creates a new certificate for me but I need same app id to submit an app to iOS app store. So I ask to change id to previous one but he said he can't. Can someone help me what to do? As far I know to `update existing app u need same app id`

Comment: Just edit it and download new one, remove old one then install new

Comment: Admin remove my privilege to edit it. So i ask him edit and he say it can't edit existing one.

Comment: you have to admin privilege to edit profile.

Comment: Please check new answer i submit now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well just **edit** the **provisional profile** from above **screenshot**, and choose the **certificate** which you are having in your **keychain** and download the **updated provisional profile**  and then try again!

it will work.

> Or

if you have the rights to create a new one that too will work for you, can delete the old one and create the new provisional profile for the same app Id too

> OR

you can ask somebody(having permissions) who can do this on behalf of you

**Ask you admin to edit the provisional profile again and give the new one to you**

Comment: Admin remove my privilege to edit it. So i ask him edit and he say it can't edit existing one.

Comment: Okay, if you have the rights to create a new one that too will work for you, can delete the old one and create the new provisional profile for the same app Id too.

Comment: Ask your admin to edit it with the above steps stated it will work fine

Comment: Please check new answer i submit now

Comment: thank you for help. i'm able to fix it using admin account. Look like admin doesn't have knowledge do it. Anyway thank you again

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem if existing certificate gets invalid for app ID, you can update your provisional profile by selecting new certificate(which your admin changed) in it. That's how you get valid provisional and update your keychain by installing .p12 file from newly created certificate.